# Trying to set cookie in getServerSideProps using next.js

Tags: cookies, next.js, server-side-rendering, getserversideprops

I am trying to set the cookie in the getServerSideProps, i am able to read it using `req.headers.cookie but when trying to set it, it doesnt work i tried also using other libraries like cookies-next but it did not persist:

here is the middleware which sets a Cookie and that i am able to read on getServerSideProps:

```
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

const response = NextResponse.next()

response.cookies.set({
    name: 'myCookieName',
    value: 'some-value',
    httpOnly: true,
})



return response
```

}

my getServerSideProps has nothing except for logs reading the cookie using `req.headers.cookie` and attempts to set it. Thanks for taking the time to read this

Answer (score 1):

you can use [npm cookie package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie)

```
import { serialize } from "cookie";
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";

const YourPage = () => {
  return <div>YourPage</div>;
};
export default YourPage;

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ res }) => {
  const cookie = serialize("cookieName", "cookieValue", {
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 1 week
  });

  console.log("cookie", cookie);
  console.log("res object", res);

  res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie);
  return {
    props: {},
  };
};
```

Comment: Hi @Yilmaz, thanks for the suggestion but when refreshing and removing the set after setting once the data does not persist only the one in the middleware is shown

Comment: you could add `maxAge` property. you can check the npm docs for more oprions or ts suggestion

Comment: tried using maxAge as suggested but still did not persist

Comment: how do you know that it is not persisted. open chrome tools, click on "Applications" tab, on the left menu, under "Storage" category, click on cookies. you see the url for your app

Comment: So i tried with the code you gave me to set it and when doing that i logged it and it showed but then i just removed the set to see if it will log after refresh, it doesn't. So im removing this part for the second log

const cookie = serialize("cookieName", "cookieValue", {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 1 week
    });
  
  
    res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie);


and im looking that its stored on server side not browser

Comment: @CamilleBasbous i removed `setHeader`, restart the app and cookie is still there

Comment: @Yilmaz is `httpOnly: true,` necessary? I tried it and the cookie was creating but I was unable to access it in the client with `js-cookie` until I did this `httpOnly: false,`

Comment: @D.Rattansingh it is an extra layer of security https://cookie-script.com/documentation/httponly-cookies